# How to edit data received from a rest call in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I am trying to make a rest call, edit the data and then render it. The problem is that, while editing, I am getting a error - undefined even after checking if the data is there.

component I am making the rest call from:

```
function Header ({timesheetData, loadTimesheet}) {    

    useEffect(() => {
        loadTimesheet(date)
    }, [])

    return(     
        <>
            <header className="header">
            <div className="wrap">
                <span className="btn-icon">
                    <IconPlus onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)} className="icon icon-plus js-modal-init"/>  
                </span>
                <div className="header-blockquote">
                    <h1 className="header-quote">{currentQuote.quote}</h1>
                    <div className="header-cite">{currentQuote.author}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="header-inner">
                <div className="wrap">
                    <VegaIcon className="logo" alt="VegaIT"/>
                    <div className="date-wrap">
                        <IconCalendar className="icon icon-plus js-modal-init"/>
                        //
                        <time>{timesheetData.timesheet.loading ? "asd"  : edit(timesheetData)  }</time>
                        //
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
            </>
        )
}


function edit(timesheetData){
    let newDate = timesheetData.timesheet.date
    newDate = newDate.split("-")
    newDate = newDate.reverse()
    return  newDate.join("/")
}
```

the redux action:

```
export const  loadTimesheet = (date) => {

    let url = "http://localhost:8080/api/timesheet/" + date

    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(getTimesheet)
        axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            const timesheet = response.data
            dispatch(getTimesheetSuccess(timesheet))
        })
        .catch(error =>  {
            const errorMsg = error.message
            dispatch(getTimesheetFailure)
        })
    }
}
```

Edit: added my mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        timesheetData: state.timesheet
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        loadTimesheet: (date) => dispatch(loadTimesheet(date))
    }
}
```

Edit2: The code: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-tharp-o9ibe

Answer (score 0):

use [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch), [mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch):

```
import getTimesheet from '../actions/...'

Header ({timesheetData, loadTimesheet}) => {
 
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadTimesheet: () => dispatch(getTimesheet()),
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { timesheetData: state.timesheetData };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

also in component:

before render:
check that you have:

- timesheetData - `not undefined`
- timesheetData.timesheet  - `not undefined`
- timesheetData.timesheet.loading  - `not undefined`

  ```
  const hasData = timesheetData && !timesheetData.timesheet.loading;
  const time = hasData ? edit(timesheetData): "asd";
  ```

in render:

```
<time>{time}</time>
```

Comment: I already did, but nothing changed. I have left it out of the question for it's clarity.

Comment: It's no giving me the undefined error anymore, but It's not making the rest call either now. Most likely because of the changes in mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps. I will add mine previous ones to the question if that helps.

Comment: I could try doing that, but not sure if it would work since I am using localhost api.

Comment: you can write mocks for fetch or api, because I think they work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228992/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-aratata).